# Ember JS: Determine what component is nested

Tags: ember.js

In the following example, I was wondering if there way to know from the parent component what child component is nested inside of it? I am trying to render something in the parent component only when the child-component-1 is not present is that possible?

```
{{#parent-component}}
    {{child-component-1}}
    {{child-component-2}}
{{/parent-component}}
```

Comment: There is a somewhat hacky way, which involves passing an action to the child components that they call to register themselves in the parent. Do you really need this?

Comment: Why would child-component-1 not be present? Is it because an array in the model is missing an element? Or because the user removed it? If there's data in the model that would impact the child components, I'd just work with that instead.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to have the children register themselves with the parent, something like this:

```
import ParentComponent from 'some/where/parent-component';

registerWithParent: Ember.on('didInsertElement', function() {
    let parent= this.nearestOfType(ParentComponent);
    if (parent) {
        parent.registerChild(this);
    }
}
```

Then, in the ParentComponent:

```
registerChild: function() {
    // do something to keep track of children
}
```